# Parse JSON output and extract value in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

My json output from service now is

```
[{"errno": "0","num_keys": "0"},
 {"errno": "1","num_keys": "2"},
 {"errno": "3","num_keys": "4"},
 {"errno": "5","num_keys": "6"}]
```

In this, i want to extract each value if keys errno and num_keys.

I am using the below code:

```
var request = new sn_ws.RESTMessageV2();
request.setEndpoint("url");
request.setHttpMethod('GET');
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
request.setRequestHeader('X-IPM-Username','some name');
request.setRequestHeader('X-IPM-Password','some password');
var response = request.execute();
var result=response.getBody();
```

Here how to extract the values?

```
var result=response.json();
```

Comment: Please, please do not send **passwords** in a GET request. HTTP verb semantics be @#%$ed.

Comment: @JaredSmith ,thanks. here i use encoded password only, just to show code i pasted it like this

Comment: I'm not sure why the request is relevant here. If you have some JSON, and want to extract some data, it doesn't matter where that JSON came from.

Comment: @Jared If it's an API that requires authentication, and it's not a *login action* (i.e. something where you get a token for the right username + password), then there's absolutely nothing wrong with this. Arguably the API should use the `Authorization` header instead of `X-...`, but whatever…

Comment: I tried it and you're response body example has extra comma at the end which breaks the array: [ a, b, ]

Comment: @imiro sorry, thats by mistake and i removed it

Answer (score 1):

This has likely been asked previously, but your question itself has the answer in it. You'll want to use [`JSON.parse()`](https://www.w3schools.com/Js/js_json_parse.asp) parse your JSON string into a JavaScript object, perhaps like this:

`var result = JSON.parse(response.json());`

Your resulting object, from your example response, would be an array of objects which you can access or iterate through:

`var error0 = result[0];`

Note that you may run into errors if your HTTP request fails or doesn't return properly formatted JSON.

Comment: i tried this parse method, it gave result as****  Script: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] when i printed it using 

var result=JSON.parse(response.getBody());

gs.print(result);

Comment: @impika Sounds like it parsed successfully. Now you just need to loop through the array and do whatever it is you need to do with those objects.

Comment: @impika You are on the correct path! This is because the resulting object is an array of objects, you must iterate through the array to access the data. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Answer (score 0):

Simple parse :

```
var json = '{"myjsons":[{"errno": "0","num_keys": "0"},{"errno": "2","num_keys": "3"}]}';


var jsonData = JSON.parse(json);
for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.myjsons.length; i++) {
    var myjsons= jsonData.myjsons[i];
    console.log(myjsons.errno);
     console.log(myjsons.num_keys);
}
```

Also like this :

```
var arr =  [{"errno": "0","num_keys": "0"},
 {"errno": "1","num_keys": "2"},
 {"errno": "3","num_keys": "4"},
 {"errno": "5","num_keys": "6"}];

arr.forEach(function(value){
  console.log('errno: ' + value.errno);
  console.log('num_keys: ' + value.num_keys);

});
```

Comment: It may be applicable if one block of key value pair, however in my case it is 4 blocks of values

Comment: @impika look my update

Comment: what is here "myjsons" in jsonData.myjsons.length?

apologies that i am a beginner in javascript

Comment: @impika Update your post with the full-json

Comment: it is same as what i posted, it doesnt have any variable/key assigned. I hit URL with get request, the output is what i posted

Comment: @impika I have made update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203329/discussion-between-devlogin-and-impika).